# pivot drop Nan Values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Having a pivot as below:

[image: img12]

I was trying to drop the NaN values:

`matrix = matrix.drop(index=None, columns=None)`

Its not working.

```
ValueError: Need to specify at least one of 'labels', 'index' or 'columns'
```

Is there any other way to do this?
Expected output:

[image: img3]

Comment: if you dont provide labels,index or column name how it can drop? use `dropna` instead of `drop`

Answer (score 0):

[drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html?highlight=drop#pandas.DataFrame.drop) is for dropping entire rows or columns (independed of their values). Use [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to delete rows or columns where values are NAN

Comment: I need to drop entire row and column

Comment: Then specify the row or colum as your error message says

Comment: ..or use dropna as i suggested if you want to drop rows or columns automatically if they are nan

Comment: check dupe for solution